# Drag&Drop Folder Download

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, folder, download

I implement a SharePoint website as an Intranet-Site.

Is it possible for the employees to download folders via Drag & Drop?

I don't want Zip-Archives named Onedrivexxx.zip.

Thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer to your question is **No**.

Currently this is not possible using SharePoint OOTB capabilities.

**Additional information**:

If you're downloading folder/files regularly from a Shared folders or document libraries then you can [add and sync shared folders to your own OneDrive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-and-sync-shared-folders-to-onedrive-8a63cd47-1526-4cd8-bd09-ee3f9bfc1504).

Comment: If you are a developer and you know SPFx development then you can try developing your custom solution with [ListView Command Set extension](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api).

Comment: Ok. unfortunately we don´t allow Onedrive. Hope Microsoft bring this feature someday